# ubuntu avoid login after power save

Tags: login, power-management, 21.04

I have set power save after 15' of inactivity. The problem is that I need to log in again when I am back (for instance by moving the mouse). What is the way to avoid log in?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be in settings, under Privacy -> Screen lock.  You might want to disable the automatic screen lock, and the lock screen on suspend.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! it worked